# How to know which items are from which array when combining

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

If I have two arrays and combine them I want to know which items were originally in each array. For example I have these two arrays:

```
primaryTypes = [
new PrimaryType(43),
new PrimaryType(86),
new PrimaryType(12),
];

secondaryTypes = [
new SecondaryType(58),
new SecondaryType(8),
new SecondaryType(98),
];
```

I combine the two arrays like this:

```
let resultsArray: any[] = [];
resultsArray = this.primarytypes.concat(this.secondarytypes);
```

If I'm iterating through resultsArray and wanted to get a sum of the amounts that were originally in the primaryTypes array, how could I determine which items were originally in primaryTypes and only add those items together?

Comment: Is there any reason you can't simply add the values in `primaryTypes` _before_ you merge the two arrays?

Comment: That's a good point. I still was wondering if there is a way to check which items originally came from each array.

Comment: Perhaps the [instanceof](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/instanceof) operator does what you need.

Comment: That was what I needed. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the `instanceof` operator. Like this:

```
resultsArray.forEach(item => {
    if (item instanceof PrimaryType) {
        //...
    }

    if (item instanceof SecondaryType) {
        //...
    }
});
```

Comment: Thanks for the help. That was what I needed.

Comment: glad to help you :)